# Trying to expunge a patient but it's not working

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am trying to delete a patient using delete and $expunge, I am able to do it at system level but  at the instance level keep getting 405 method not allowed.

System-Level
http://localhost:8080/smart-pgd-fhir/v1/$expunge
Post
{
"resourceType": "Parameters",
"parameter": [
{
"name": "expungeDeletedResources",
"valueBoolean": true
},{
"name": "expungePreviousVersions",
"valueBoolean": true
}
]
}

Instance-level
http://localhost:8080/smart-pgd-fhir/v1/Patient/7f73bd2b-2647-4c0d-8dc9-798ffe719924/$expunge
Post

{
"resourceType": "Parameters",
"parameter": [
{
"name": "expungeDeletedResources",
"valueBoolean": true
},{
"name": "expungePreviousVersions",
"valueBoolean": true
}
]
}

I am using this example https://smilecdr.com/docs/fhir_repository/deleting_data.html#expunge

Comment: The code needs to be here and not in a link - and short enough to just show the poroblem and no more

Comment: thats the link which shows how to pass expunge parameter. which I did but its not working http://localhost:8080/smart-pgd-fhir/v1/$expunge

Comment: I cannot see the code in the question or the expected result